# ODBC-based connection with SQL Server Using Port 1433 despite setting up different port in .odbc.ini

Tags: sql-server, odbc, unixodbc, netstat

I am having an issue where - even though I have set up the .odbc.ini to connect to a SQL Server with static port 9088 (I have already added this as another listening port in SQL Server side, in addition to port 1433), whenever I go to netstat -ano in the target SQL Server, it still shows the connection is on port 1433. I have no firewalls between these two databases.

What else can I do to make sure the connection is to 9088 instead of 1433?

[image]

These are the different .odbc.ini configurations I have tried but it still keeps going to port 1433!

```
[<SERVER NAME>]

Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2260.0

ServerName=<Server Name>

Port=9088
```

Or

```
[<SERVER NAME>]

Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2260.0

ServerName=<Server Name>,9088
```

Or

```
[<SERVER NAME>]

Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2260.0

ServerName=<Server Name>:9088
```

Thanks and regards,

Esteban

Comment: How exactly the corresponding endpoint is configured? Did you grant CONNECT to this endpoint to your logins?

Comment: Yes sir that has been configured on the SQL server side. I have gone on SQL Server Config Mgmt -> Default instance -> TCP/IP settings -> Enabled and added comma separated port result is “1433,9088” and then restarted SQL server. Screenshot above shows port 9088 listening.

Comment: I asked you not about adding another port, but about configuring the ENDPOINT and granting CONNECT on this endpoint. If it's not done, the default port will be used

Comment: Thanks sepupic! I understand now - I have there was actually a configuration issue on the client side with the port it was pointing to. I have corrected it and checked the endpoints/grant connects and it's working now.